# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, flask

I have the following structure in my project :
\myapp
    application.py
    \include
       hello.html
so the folder myapp contains application.py and the folder include.
the folder include contains hello.html.
the following code :
application.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python 2.7.6
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask,render_template
import psycopg2
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def fihoum():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="carto", user="postgres",
           password="daed5Aemo", host="192.168.12.54")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM carto.\"BADGES_SFR\"")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('hello.html', titre="Données du client
   BADGES_SFR !",mots=rows)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), 
            port=int(os.getenv('PORT',5000)),debug=True)
```

the following code hello.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>{{ titre }}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>{{ titre }}</h1>
        <ul>
        {% for mot in mots %}
            <li>{{ mot }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

THE PROBLEM: Whene I run the program application.py I have this mistake :
**jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound**

TemplateNotFound: hello.html
thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

The template folder defaults to `templates\`; so you should rename `include` to `templates`.